# 1st uniqueness theorem of a primary decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have a problem with one step of the proof of the 1st uniqueness theorem of a primary decomposition in Atiyah, MacDonald *Commutative Algebra*.

Theorem 4.5. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a decomposable ideal in the ring $A$ and $\mathfrak{a}=\bigcap_{1\leq i\leq n}\mathfrak{q}_i$ be a minimal primary decomposition of $\mathfrak{a}$. Let $\mathfrak{p}_i=\mathrm{rad}(\mathfrak{q}_i)$, ${1\leq i\leq n}$. Then the $\mathfrak{p}_i$ are precisely the prime ideals which occur in the set of ideals $\mathrm{rad}(\mathfrak{a}:x)$, $x\in A$, and hence are independent of the particular decomposition of $\mathfrak{a}$.

I can see that the statement is true for $x\notin \mathfrak{a}$, but for the case $x\in \mathfrak{a}$, $(\mathfrak{a}:x)=(1)$ and so $\mathrm{rad}(\mathfrak{a}:x)=(1)$? What am I missing here? Are the writers just ignoring this case since $(1)$ is not prime?

Comment: The formulation allows them to ignore that case as they say that "the $p_i$ are precisely the *prime* ideals which occur in ..."

Comment: So I thought, but I wanted another opinion, so that I hadn't misunderstood. Thank you

Comment: Off topic: I don't think the primary decomposition is that important to learn, especially for beginners.

Comment: Off topic: I think the primary decomposition is very important to learn, especially for beginners.